# Choosing correct connecting words for drawing a parallel between two actions

Tags: word-request

I am trying to draw a parallel between two actions in one sentence, but am having trouble in choosing suitable connecting words. What choice of words would sound natural here?

> 1. **Just like** Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I chose not to start the today's meeting from my
>    complaints, **too**.
> 2. **Just as** Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I chose not to start the today's meeting from my complaints, **too**.
> 3. **Just as** Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I **likewise** chose not to start the today's meeting from my
>    complaints.
> 4. **Just like** Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I chose not to start the today's meeting from my
>    complaints **either**.
> 5. **Just as** Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I chose not to start the today's meeting from my complaints
>    **either**.
> 6. **Just like** Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I **in the same manner** chose not to start the today's
>    meeting from my complaints.
> 7. **Just as** Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right
>    away, I **also** chose not to start the today's meeting from my
>    complaints.
> 8. ?

Comment: I would suggest "Just as Jack, three years ago, didn't dare/hadn't dared to voice his suspicions right away, I chose not to start today's meeting with my complaints". You could include _too_ or _also_, but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: @Astralbee - (1) Did you see those 7 sentences in my question? Those are the results of my research. My question would have looked like no-research question if I had only written one sentence and asked something like "Is this correct?".

Comment: @Astralbee - (2) Besides, I don't know what kind of resource I would need to refer to in order to get the right connecting words specifically for expressing a parallel between two things in one sentence. There are many resources on conjunctions, but I haven't found any answering my specific question. If you have one (which I doubt), please, give me a link. And as for "your being here not for doing my homework", it's very simple -- no one forces you, me included, to answer my question.

Comment: @Astralbee - Really? How would thesaurus help me then determine, which words I should choose for my sentence? A thesaurus is good to get the precise meaning of a word that you already have on hand, but it contains almost no info on how those words must be used. It does little in letting you know, which word would be suitable for your particular case.

Comment: @brilliant Ok I'll give you an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is *best* would be a matter of opinion, but some are wrong:

- <s>Just like Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I chose not to start the today's meeting from my complaints, too.</s>
- <s>Just as Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I chose not to start the today's meeting from my complaints, too.</s>

These don't feel right, firstly because 'too' means "as well" - Jack *didn't* do something, so you can't say "as well" to something that *didn't* happen. You *could* use it if you were focusing on the *choice* not to, because the act of making the choice is something that *did* happen - but you don't say that Jack chose not to, you said he "didn't dare to", so the two are not quite comparable.

- Just as Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I likewise chose not to start <s>the</s> today's meeting from my complaints.
- Just like Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I chose not to start <s>the</s> today's meeting from my complaints either.

These two seem okay, except for the rogue articles. You're still not giving an exact comparison (Jack didn't dare, but you chose), but by using 'likewise' you state that the two are similar.

- <s>Just as Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I chose not to start the today's meeting from my complaints either.</s>
- <s>Just like Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I in the same manner chose not to start the today's meeting from my complaints</s>
- <s>Just as Jack 3 years ago didn't dare to voice his suspicion right away, I also chose not to start the today's meeting from my complaints.</s>

"From my complaints" isn't really idiomatic - if you mean they would be the first point of discussion in your meeting, we'd say "start the meeting *with* my complaints.

All things considered, to make the most idiomatic comparison, you need to focus on the point that makes the two clauses comparable - is it the decision, the non-voicing of complaints/suspicion, or is it that you share similar complaints? You also have a lot going on in the first clause - the fact that it was 3 years ago, the fact he had suspicious, and the choice not to voice them. If you could make that more succinct it would be clearer on which point you are comparing.

I would personally say:

> Just as Jack didn't immediately voice his suspicions 3 years ago, I chose not to start today's meeting with my complaints.

or

> Jack didn't immediately voice his suspicions 3 years ago, likewise, I chose not to start today's meeting with my complaints.

or

> 3 years ago, Jack chose to hold back his suspicions. I chose not to start today's meeting with mine, either.

This last one makes it even more succinct by eliminating the duplicate words - if you both had comparable suspicions, you don't need to say it twice.

Comment: WOW! This one is a very much well-explained, informative and right-to-the-point answer. Thank you!